# DBInit ChannelPreparer Faliture

Tags: intershop

We are trying to execute `DBInit` but it fails with the following error:

> [2019-08-07 10:50:39.292 +0200] Failure: init_a1:Class12
>   ChannelPreparer
>   [hr.a1.init.data.organization.Channel,hr.a1.init.data.organization.ChannelLocalization,ProcessChannel-DBInit]
>   5089ms, see the error log. Error message: Object is not valid:
>   'com.intershop.component.mvc.internal.catalog.RepositoryPOKey[G97AqHVyOkQAAAFsl9TnGGtF]'
>   at table [REPOSITORY]

We can't be sure, but it looks like it started happening after the change of JDK `(Oracle JDK ->  AdoptOpenJDK Hotspot 8)`. Current version of `Intershop` used is `7.10.10.1`.

Additional ERROR log:

```
[2019-08-07 10:50:39.214 +0200] ERROR matija2 ES1 dbinit [] [init_a1:Class12 ChannelPreparer [hr.a1.init.data.organization.Channel,hr.a1.init.data.organization.ChannelLocalization,ProcessChannel-DBInit]] com.intershop.beehive.core.pipelet.pipeline.ExecutePipeline [] [Unknown] [dY3AqHVyOdEAAAFsadTnGGtF] [HNrAqHVy4AsAAAFsadTnGGtF] "main" ISH-CORE-2490: Synchronous called pipeline 'CreateSalesChannel-CreateChannelObjects' of application 'Shop@A1-Site (app=tomato.Backoffice)' has finished with exception:  com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineCallStackException: com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.pipeline.PipelineExecutionException: Required input parameter 'AppID' missing of pipeline 'ProcessApplication defined in cartridge sld_ch_base' and start node 'Create'!
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.Pipeline.executePipeline(Pipeline.java:1038)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:641)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:484)
    at com.intershop.beehive.pipeline.internal.PipelineEngineImpl.executePipeline(PipelineEngineImpl.java:97)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:421)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:250)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.pipelet.pipeline.ExecutePipeline.execute(ExecutePipeline.java:175)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipeletNode.executeNode(PipeletNode.java:346)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.Pipeline.executeNode(Pipeline.java:1098)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.Pipeline.executePipeline(Pipeline.java:926)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:641)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:484)
    at com.intershop.beehive.pipeline.internal.PipelineEngineImpl.executePipeline(PipelineEngineImpl.java:97)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:421)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:326)
    at com.intershop.component.mvc.dbinit.preparer.ChannelPreparer.createRepository(ChannelPreparer.java:414)
    at com.intershop.component.mvc.dbinit.preparer.ChannelPreparer.createChannel(ChannelPreparer.java:303)
    at com.intershop.component.mvc.dbinit.preparer.ChannelPreparer.prepare(ChannelPreparer.java:110)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.execute(DBInit.java:372)
    at com.intershop.tool.common.PreparerUtils.execute(PreparerUtils.java:275)
    at com.intershop.tool.common.PreparerUtils.executePreparers(PreparerUtils.java:237)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.prepareCartridge(DBInit.java:548)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.cartridge.Cartridge.onDBInit(Cartridge.java:572)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.execute(DBInit.java:471)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.run(DBInit.java:634)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.main(DBInit.java:148)
Caused by: com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.pipeline.PipelineExecutionException: Required input parameter 'AppID' missing of pipeline 'ProcessApplication defined in cartridge sld_ch_base' and start node 'Create'!
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.StartNode.copyParameters(StartNode.java:275)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.StartNode.createSubDictionary(StartNode.java:228)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.StartNode.executeNode(StartNode.java:175)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.Pipeline.executeNode(Pipeline.java:1098)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.CallNode.executeNode(CallNode.java:208)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.Pipeline.executeNode(Pipeline.java:1098)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.Pipeline.executePipeline(Pipeline.java:926)
    ... 25 common frames omitted

System Information
------------------
RequestID: HNrAqHVy4AsAAAFsadTnGGtF
StartDate: Wed Aug 07 10:50:34 CEST 2019
SessionType: UNKNOWN
ServerName: 
ServerPort: -1

Request Information
-------------------
URI: 
Method: 
PathInfo: 
QueryString: 
Remote User: 

Request Parameters
------------------
[2019-08-07 10:50:39.237 +0200] ERROR matija2 ES1 dbinit [] [init_a1:Class12 ChannelPreparer [hr.a1.init.data.organization.Channel,hr.a1.init.data.organization.ChannelLocalization,ProcessChannel-DBInit]] com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl [] [Unknown] [dY3AqHVyOdEAAAFsadTnGGtF] [HNrAqHVy4AsAAAFsadTnGGtF] "main" Executing error handler of pipeline (ProcessChannel) because of exception com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.pipeline.PipelineExecutionException: Unexpected end of pipeline (pipelineName=ProcessChannel, subPipelineName=CreateSalesChannel, nodeID=ExecutePipeline0)
        near Node ExecutePipeline0 (Pipelet ExecutePipeline)
        at Pipeline CreateSalesChannel-AfterChannelApplicationHook (Cartridge sld_ch_consumer_plugin)
        at Pipeline ProcessChannel-DBInit (Cartridge sld_enterprise_app)
Caused by: com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.pipeline.PipelineExecutionException: Unexpected end of pipeline (pipelineName=ProcessChannel, subPipelineName=CreateSalesChannel, nodeID=ExecutePipeline0)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.Pipeline.executePipeline(Pipeline.java:1002)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:641)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:484)
    at com.intershop.beehive.pipeline.internal.PipelineEngineImpl.executePipeline(PipelineEngineImpl.java:97)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:421)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.pipeline.PipelineProcessorImpl.executePipeline(PipelineProcessorImpl.java:326)
    at com.intershop.component.mvc.dbinit.preparer.ChannelPreparer.createRepository(ChannelPreparer.java:414)
    at com.intershop.component.mvc.dbinit.preparer.ChannelPreparer.createChannel(ChannelPreparer.java:303)
    at com.intershop.component.mvc.dbinit.preparer.ChannelPreparer.prepare(ChannelPreparer.java:110)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.execute(DBInit.java:372)
    at com.intershop.tool.common.PreparerUtils.execute(PreparerUtils.java:275)
    at com.intershop.tool.common.PreparerUtils.executePreparers(PreparerUtils.java:237)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.prepareCartridge(DBInit.java:548)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.cartridge.Cartridge.onDBInit(Cartridge.java:572)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.execute(DBInit.java:471)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.run(DBInit.java:634)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.main(DBInit.java:148)

System Information
------------------
RequestID: HNrAqHVy4AsAAAFsadTnGGtF
StartDate: Wed Aug 07 10:50:34 CEST 2019
SessionType: UNKNOWN
ServerName: 
ServerPort: -1

Request Information
-------------------
URI: 
Method: 
PathInfo: 
QueryString: 
Remote User: 

Request Parameters
------------------
[2019-08-07 10:50:39.292 +0200] ERROR matija2 ES1 dbinit [] [init_a1:Class12 ChannelPreparer [hr.a1.init.data.organization.Channel,hr.a1.init.data.organization.ChannelLocalization,ProcessChannel-DBInit]] com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit [] [] [] [] "main" [1542506058] Error executing init_a1:Class12 ChannelPreparer [hr.a1.init.data.organization.Channel,hr.a1.init.data.organization.ChannelLocalization,ProcessChannel-DBInit] com.intershop.beehive.orm.capi.common.OCAException: Object is not valid: 'com.intershop.component.mvc.internal.catalog.RepositoryPOKey[G97AqHVyOkQAAAFsl9TnGGtF]' at table [REPOSITORY]
    at com.intershop.beehive.orm.capi.common.ORMObject.getRelationCollection(ORMObject.java:902)
    at com.intershop.beehive.orm.internal.common.RelationCollection.getInternalCollection(RelationCollection.java:53)
    at com.intershop.beehive.orm.internal.common.RelationCollection.toArray(RelationCollection.java:94)
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:178)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.domain.ExtensibleObjectPO.getAttributeValues(ExtensibleObjectPO.java:3334)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.domain.ExtensibleObjectPO.getLocalizedAttributeValue(ExtensibleObjectPO.java:3154)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.domain.ExtensibleObjectPO.putLocalizedString(ExtensibleObjectPO.java:402)
    at com.intershop.component.mvc.internal.catalog.RepositoryPO.setDisplayName(RepositoryPO.java:140)
    at com.intershop.component.mvc.dbinit.preparer.ChannelPreparer.setLocalizableChannelAttributes(ChannelPreparer.java:480)
    at com.intershop.component.mvc.dbinit.preparer.ChannelPreparer.createChannel(ChannelPreparer.java:313)
    at com.intershop.component.mvc.dbinit.preparer.ChannelPreparer.prepare(ChannelPreparer.java:110)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.execute(DBInit.java:372)
    at com.intershop.tool.common.PreparerUtils.execute(PreparerUtils.java:275)
    at com.intershop.tool.common.PreparerUtils.executePreparers(PreparerUtils.java:237)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.prepareCartridge(DBInit.java:548)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.cartridge.Cartridge.onDBInit(Cartridge.java:572)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.execute(DBInit.java:471)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.run(DBInit.java:634)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.main(DBInit.java:148)

[2019-08-07 10:50:39.296 +0200] ERROR matija2 ES1 dbinit [] [init_a1:Class12 ChannelPreparer [hr.a1.init.data.organization.Channel,hr.a1.init.data.organization.ChannelLocalization,ProcessChannel-DBInit]] com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit [] [] [] [] "main" [1964078722] Error executing init_a1:Class16 UpdateApplicationLocaleAndCurrencyPreparer [hr.a1.init.data.organization.Application] com.intershop.beehive.orm.capi.common.ORMException: Nested transactions are not supported
    at com.intershop.beehive.orm.internal.transaction.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:267)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.execute(DBInit.java:350)
    at com.intershop.tool.common.PreparerUtils.execute(PreparerUtils.java:275)
    at com.intershop.tool.common.PreparerUtils.executePreparers(PreparerUtils.java:237)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.prepareCartridge(DBInit.java:548)
    at com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.cartridge.Cartridge.onDBInit(Cartridge.java:572)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.execute(DBInit.java:471)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.run(DBInit.java:634)
    at com.intershop.tool.dbinit.DBInit.main(DBInit.java:148)
```

This is the content of out Channel.properties file:

```
Channel.1.Organization = A1
Channel.1.ID = Shop
Channel.1.TypeCode=52
Channel.1.ApplicationTypeCode=51
Channel.1.Apps=a1.Web,a1.Homebox
Channel.1.DefaultAppTypeID=a1.Web

Channel.2.Organization = A1
Channel.2.ID = Tomato
Channel.2.TypeCode=52
Channel.2.ApplicationTypeCode=51
Channel.2.Apps=tomato.Web
Channel.2.DefaultAppTypeID=tomato.Web
```

**UPDATE:** Application type registry (apps.component)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<components xmlns="http://www.intershop.de/component/2010">

  <!-- ************************************************************************************ -->
  <!-- * Application Type "a1Shop.Backoffice" * -->
  <!-- ************************************************************************************ -->

  <!-- new instance for storefront applications managed by this Channel Note: This registry needs be assigned to the EnterpriseBackoffice as 
    well as Channel (B2CBackoffice) -->
  <instance name="a1Shop.Backoffice.ApplicationTypes" with="AppRegistry" />

  <!-- declaration of the cartridge list -->
  <instance with="CartridgeListProvider" name="a1Shop.Backoffice.Cartridges">
    <fulfill value="app_bo_a1" requirement="selectedCartridge" />
    <fulfill value="app_core_a1" requirement="selectedCartridge" />

    <!-- Possibility 2: derive from standard webshop if you want to use the same cartridges like standard webshop -->
    <fulfill requirement="parent" with="intershop.B2CBackoffice.Cartridges" />

  </instance>

  <!-- definition of the application type -->
  <instance with="ApplicationType" name="a1Shop.Backoffice">
    <fulfill value="a1Shop.Backoffice" requirement="id" />
    <fulfill value="a1-shop-bo" requirement="urlIdentifier" />
    <fulfill with="a1Shop.Backoffice.Cartridges" requirement="cartridgeListProvider" />
    <fulfill requirement="namedObject">
      <instance with="NamedObject">
        <fulfill requirement="name" value="ChannelApps_52" />
        <!-- register the AppRegistry containing all storefront applications of this channel -->
        <fulfill requirement="object" with="a1Shop.Backoffice.ApplicationTypes" />
      </instance>
    </fulfill>
    <!-- put additional NamedObjects, that are required by the particular business features -->
    <!-- ... -->
  </instance>

  <!-- registration of the application type to the AppEngine -->
  <fulfill of="AppEngine" with="a1Shop.Backoffice" requirement="app" />

  <!-- register the custom B2CBackoffice to the Enterprise Backoffice of your choose -->
  <fulfill of="intershop.EnterpriseBackoffice" requirement="namedObject">
    <instance with="NamedObject">
      <fulfill value="ChannelBackofficeApplicationType_52" requirement="name" />
      <fulfill with="a1Shop.Backoffice" requirement="object" />
    </instance>
  </fulfill>

  <!-- ************************************************************************************ -->
  <!-- * Application Type "tomato.Backoffice" * -->
  <!-- ************************************************************************************ -->

  <!-- new instance for storefront applications managed by this Channel Note: This registry needs be assigned to the EnterpriseBackoffice as 
    well as Channel (B2CBackoffice) -->
  <instance name="tomato.Backoffice.ApplicationTypes" with="AppRegistry" />

  <!-- declaration of the cartridge list -->
  <instance with="CartridgeListProvider" name="tomato.Backoffice.Cartridges">
    <fulfill value="app_bo_a1" requirement="selectedCartridge" />
    <fulfill value="app_core_a1" requirement="selectedCartridge" />

    <!-- Derive from standard webshop if you want to use the same cartridges like standard webshop -->
    <fulfill requirement="parent" with="intershop.B2CBackoffice.Cartridges" />
  </instance>

  <!-- definition of the application type -->
  <instance with="ApplicationType" name="tomato.Backoffice">
    <fulfill requirement="id" value="tomato.Backoffice" />
    <fulfill requirement="urlIdentifier" value="a1-tomato-bo" />
    <fulfill requirement="cartridgeListProvider" with="tomato.Backoffice.Cartridges" />
    <fulfill requirement="namedObject">
      <instance with="NamedObject">
        <fulfill requirement="name" value="ChannelApps_52" />
        <!-- register the AppRegistry containing all storefront applications of this channel -->
        <fulfill requirement="object" with="tomato.Backoffice.ApplicationTypes" />
      </instance>
    </fulfill>
    <!-- put additional NamedObjects, that are required by the particular business features -->
    <!-- ... -->
  </instance>

  <!-- registration of the application type to the AppEngine -->
  <fulfill of="AppEngine" with="tomato.Backoffice" requirement="app" />

  <!-- register the custom B2CBackoffice to the Enterprise Backoffice of your choose -->
  <fulfill of="intershop.EnterpriseBackoffice" requirement="namedObject">
    <instance with="NamedObject">
      <fulfill value="ChannelBackofficeApplicationType_52" requirement="name" />
      <fulfill with="tomato.Backoffice" requirement="object" />
    </instance>
  </fulfill>


  <!-- ************************************************************************************ -->
  <!-- * Application Type "a1.Web" * -->
  <!-- ************************************************************************************ -->

  <instance name="a1.Web.Cartridges" with="CartridgeListProvider">
    <fulfill requirement="selectedCartridge" value="app_sf_a1_shop_cm" />
    <fulfill requirement="selectedCartridge" value="app_sf_a1_shop" />
    <fulfill requirement="selectedCartridge" value="app_core_a1" />

    <!-- include the cartridges of another cartridge list provider -->
    <fulfill requirement="parent" with="intershop.B2CResponsive.Cartridges" />
  </instance>

  <instance name="a1.Web" with="ApplicationType">
    <fulfill requirement="id" value="a1.Web" />
    <fulfill requirement="urlIdentifier" value="a1-shop" />
    <fulfill requirement="cartridgeListProvider" with="a1.Web.Cartridges" />
    <fulfill requirement="namedObject">
      <instance with="NamedObject">
        <fulfill requirement="name" value="ApplicationCallInterface" />
        <fulfill requirement="object">
          <instance with="b2c.B2CApplicationCallInterface">
            <fulfill requirement="defaultCallTarget" value="Default-Start" />
            <fulfill requirement="app" with="a1.Web" />
          </instance>
        </fulfill>
      </instance>
    </fulfill>
    <fulfill requirement="namedObject">
      <instance with="NamedObject">
        <fulfill requirement="name" value="PreviewConfigurationModel" />
        <fulfill requirement="object" with="intershop.B2CResponsive.PreviewConfigurationModel" />
      </instance>
    </fulfill>
  </instance>

  <fulfill requirement="namedObject" of="a1.Web" with="intershop.B2CWebShop.RESTAPI" />

  <fulfill requirement="app" with="a1.Web" of="AppEngine" />
  <fulfill requirement="app" with="a1.Web" of="a1Shop.Backoffice.ApplicationTypes" />

  <!-- ************************************************************************************ -->
  <!-- * Application Type "a1.Homebox" * -->
  <!-- ************************************************************************************ -->

  <instance name="a1.Homebox.Cartridges" with="CartridgeListProvider">
    <fulfill requirement="selectedCartridge" value="app_sf_a1_homebox" />
    <fulfill requirement="selectedCartridge" value="app_core_a1" />

    <!-- include the cartridges of another cartridge list provider -->
    <fulfill requirement="parent" with="intershop.B2CResponsive.Cartridges" />
  </instance>

  <instance name="a1.Homebox" with="ApplicationType">
    <fulfill requirement="id" value="a1.Homebox" />
    <fulfill requirement="urlIdentifier" value="a1-homebox" />
    <fulfill requirement="cartridgeListProvider" with="a1.Homebox.Cartridges" />
    <fulfill requirement="namedObject">
      <instance with="NamedObject">
        <fulfill requirement="name" value="ApplicationCallInterface" />
        <fulfill requirement="object">
          <instance with="b2c.B2CApplicationCallInterface">
            <fulfill requirement="defaultCallTarget" value="Default-Start" />
            <fulfill requirement="app" with="a1.Homebox" />
          </instance>
        </fulfill>
      </instance>
    </fulfill>
    <fulfill requirement="namedObject">
      <instance with="NamedObject">
        <fulfill requirement="name" value="PreviewConfigurationModel" />
        <fulfill requirement="object" with="intershop.B2CResponsive.PreviewConfigurationModel" />
      </instance>
    </fulfill>
  </instance>

  <fulfill requirement="namedObject" of="a1.Homebox" with="intershop.B2CWebShop.RESTAPI" />

  <fulfill requirement="app" with="a1.Homebox" of="AppEngine" />
  <fulfill requirement="app" with="a1.Homebox" of="a1Shop.Backoffice.ApplicationTypes" />


  <!-- ************************************************************************************ -->
  <!-- * Application Type "tomato.Web" * -->
  <!-- ************************************************************************************ -->

  <instance name="tomato.Web.Cartridges" with="CartridgeListProvider">
    <fulfill requirement="selectedCartridge" value="app_sf_a1_tomato_cm" />
    <fulfill requirement="selectedCartridge" value="app_sf_a1_tomato" />
    <fulfill requirement="selectedCartridge" value="app_core_a1" />

    <!-- include the cartridges of another cartridge list provider -->
    <fulfill requirement="parent" with="intershop.B2CResponsive.Cartridges" />
  </instance>

  <instance name="tomato.Web" with="ApplicationType">
    <fulfill requirement="id" value="tomato.Web" />
    <fulfill requirement="urlIdentifier" value="a1-tomato" />
    <fulfill requirement="cartridgeListProvider" with="tomato.Web.Cartridges" />
    <fulfill requirement="namedObject">
      <instance with="NamedObject">
        <fulfill requirement="name" value="ApplicationCallInterface" />
        <fulfill requirement="object">
          <instance with="b2c.B2CApplicationCallInterface">
            <fulfill requirement="defaultCallTarget" value="Default-Start" />
            <fulfill requirement="app" with="tomato.Web" />
          </instance>
        </fulfill>
      </instance>
    </fulfill>
    <fulfill requirement="namedObject">
      <instance with="NamedObject">
        <fulfill requirement="name" value="PreviewConfigurationModel" />
        <fulfill requirement="object" with="intershop.B2CResponsive.PreviewConfigurationModel" />
      </instance>
    </fulfill>
  </instance>

  <fulfill requirement="namedObject" of="tomato.Web" with="intershop.B2CWebShop.RESTAPI" />

  <fulfill requirement="app" with="tomato.Web" of="AppEngine" />
  <fulfill requirement="app" with="tomato.Web" of="tomato.Backoffice.ApplicationTypes" />

</components>
```

Comment: Can you maybe check the dbinit error log for more information? Object is not valid means that the object is marked for deletion and is still changed within the same transaction.

Comment: Error log added. Also, we have compared channel and application properties with example in responsive project, but can't find any differences.

Comment: What is the difference between `tomato.Backoffice.ApplicationTypes` and `a1Shop.Backoffice.ApplicationTypes`

Comment: We have two channels, each with its own potential backoffice customization. So we defined backoffice application types for each channel.Is that wrong?

Comment: Wrong in terms of business case or wrong in terms of technically feasible? Given those business requirements I'd say you must adapt the channel creation process as well. I don't know all the details about that but it smells like there's work to be done since you deviated from the normal way for quite a bit.

Comment: Well, we don't see why this would be a problem from business side? 

But from technical side we would appreciate any suggestions. Should we just keep only one?

Comment: I understand your business case. Makes sense. Technically the channel creation works only with one application type registry. So I would suggest to keep using just one.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your properties files that is referred in that channel preparer step looks like this:

```
Channel.1.Organization = YOUR_ORG
Channel.1.ID = CHANNEL_ID
Channel.1.TypeCode=52
Channel.1.ApplicationTypeCode=51
Channel.1.Apps=<your storefront application type>
Channel.1.DefaultAppTypeID=<your storefront application type>
```

Your storefront application type id can be found in your project's `as_...` cartridge.

**Update:**
Also make sure that your application type(s) are registered with the corresponding backoffice application type registry. For example:

```
<fulfill requirement="app" with="<your storefront application type>" of="AppEngine"/>
<fulfill requirement="app" with="<your storefront application type>" of="intershop.B2CBackoffice.ApplicationTypes"/>
```

If you customized backoffice application as well, you need to replace `intershop.B2CBackoffice` with whatever you have.

Comment: I have added content of Channel properties. It looks ok to us.

Comment: Checkout my update on how to check if your application type is registered correctly. Your error clearly suggests that your application type cannot be found in the registry.

Comment: I've updated the question with application type registry. Still can't figure out where the problem is.